# How to add special characters to xml element name using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am creating an xml using xsl transformation and require to have an element with special char '@'. It may not be recommended to use it with element name but I need to.

When I use

```
<xsl:element name="@type">
                <xsl:value-of select="$type" />
            </xsl:element>
```

Getting error Element name {@type} is not a valid QName. Is there any escape sequence or any way so the @ is set in the element name as

```
<@type>
myType
</@type>
```

Comment: [Section 3.1 of the XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) says every element tag must contain a [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e804) character sequence, which does not allow `@` characters.  If you force a tag to contain `@` in its name, you no longer have a valid XML document.  So the error is correct:  `@type` is not a valid QName.  Perhaps you can use a different character, like `_` or a non-ASCII symbol?

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I'm bound to use it. In such case how can I force it to be added to XML. Is there any escape sequence or special tag to  have it considered in xml document

Comment: In theory at least, you could use `xsl:text` with `disable-output-escaping` to produce your own non-XML markup. In practice, it is not recommended and your processing chain may not support it. It might be easier to use another special char and replace it after the transformation. To stress the point again: the final result will not be XML.

Comment: I truly agree with you on this, but the need is for me to create such xml although it may not be well formed. Can you show me how xsl:text be used. does it generate element names ? Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for this.

Comment: Your question would make sense if you said you wanted to create non-XML. Generally, XSLT is designed to produce XML and works very hard to prevent you creating non-XML. However, there are tricks you can play with disable-output-escaping to get around this, as Martin explains. In general, though, if you don't want XML then I would avoid using XML tools. I would certainly avoid calling it XML, because you leave everyone confused.

Comment: Yes @MichaelKay , I would rather consider it as plain text having xml structure. I would like to know how can I output this character. I tried using the answer below but it prints &lt; instead of < also it throws error on the line below it. Not sure if I'm missing anything --Martin Honnen

Comment: It's a format that has superficial similarities to XML, and sometimes you can bend XML tools to work with such formats. But you confuse everyone if you call it XML. My preferred solution would be to use XSLT to generate something similar but well-formed, for example `<_at_type>`, and then use a text tool such as awk to convert this to `<@type>`. (Well, actually, my preferred solution would be to wring the neck of whoever came up with this requirement.)

Answer (score 0):

Given e.g.

```
<foo type="@type"/>
```

the XSLT code, if the XSLT processor serializes/is in charge of serialization and supports disable-output-escaping, the code

```
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">></xsl:text>
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">></xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

outputs e.g.

```
<@type></@type>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have tried setting the content using xsl:text as you mentioned, but I get an error Error evaluating ((text{"<"}, ...)) in xsl:value-of/@select on line 24 column 38 at the line <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>

Comment: @technocrat, I am not sure where the suggested code fails for you. Which XSLT processor do you use? Can you give the complete error message? What does "tried setting the content" mean exactly, that suggestion tries to output "markup", not "content". Anyway, minimal example not giving an error with Saxon 10 is online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFD9uuA, the same code adapted for an XSLT 1 processor at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFD9uuA/1